# How to build job using parallel and sequenced flows in spring batch?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am learning spring batch and I want to build following pipeline:

[image]

To achieve I've created the following code snippet:

```
@Configuration
public class ParallelFlowConfig {

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Bean
    public Tasklet tasklet() {
        return new CountingTasklet();
    }

    @Bean
    public Flow syncFlow() {
        return new FlowBuilder<Flow>("sync_flow")
                .start(stepBuilderFactory.get("sync_flow_step1")
                        .tasklet(tasklet())
                        .build())
                .next(stepBuilderFactory.get("sync_flow_step2")
                        .tasklet(tasklet())
                        .build())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Flow parallelFlow1() {
        return new FlowBuilder<Flow>("async_flow_1")
                .start(stepBuilderFactory.get("async_flow_1_step_1")
                        .tasklet(tasklet()).build())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Flow parallelFlow2() {
        return new FlowBuilder<Flow>("async_flow_2")
                .start(stepBuilderFactory.get("async_flow_2_step_1")
                        .tasklet(tasklet())
                        .build())
                .next(stepBuilderFactory.get("async_flow_2_step_2")
                        .tasklet(tasklet())
                        .build())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job parallelJob(TaskExecutor jobTaskExecutor) {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("sync_async_investigation_test")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(syncFlow())
                .next(parallelFlow1())
                .split(jobTaskExecutor).add(parallelFlow2())
                .end()
                .build();
    }

    public static class CountingTasklet implements Tasklet {
        private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CountingTasklet.class);

        @Override
        public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution stepContribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
            logger.info("BEFORE {} has been executed on thread {}", chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepName(), Thread.currentThread().getName());
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            logger.info("AFTER {} has been executed on thread {}", chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepName(), Thread.currentThread().getName());
            return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
        }
    }
}
```

But it produces following log:

```
2019-08-08 14:50:15.062  INFO 18004 --- [           main] h.w.c.ParallelFlowConfig$CountingTasklet : BEFORE sync_flow_step1 has been executed on thread main
2019-08-08 14:50:26.365  INFO 18004 --- [           main] h.w.c.ParallelFlowConfig$CountingTasklet : AFTER sync_flow_step1 has been executed on thread main
2019-08-08 14:50:36.219  INFO 18004 --- [           main] h.w.c.ParallelFlowConfig$CountingTasklet : BEFORE sync_flow_step2 has been executed on thread main
2019-08-08 14:50:42.559  INFO 18004 --- [           main] h.w.c.ParallelFlowConfig$CountingTasklet : AFTER sync_flow_step2 has been executed on thread main
2019-08-08 14:50:46.483  INFO 18004 --- [           main] h.w.c.ParallelFlowConfig$CountingTasklet : BEFORE async_flow_1_step_1 has been executed on thread main
2019-08-08 14:50:55.680  INFO 18004 --- [           main] h.w.c.ParallelFlowConfig$CountingTasklet : AFTER async_flow_1_step_1 has been executed on thread main
```

1. As you can see only flow1 and flow2 was executed. How to force `flow3` to be executed by spring batch?
2. As you can see the code was executing in `main` thread although I provided `taskExecutor`. How to force spring batch to run tasks in executor ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve by adding additional flow by combining two parallel flows into single flow:

```
@Bean
public Flow wrapperFlow(TaskExecutor jobTaskExecutor) {
    return new FlowBuilder<Flow>("wrapperFlow")
            .start(parallelFlow1())
            .split(jobTaskExecutor)
            .add(parallelFlow2())
            .build();
}
```

so `Job` config was changed a bit:

```
@Bean
public Job parallelJob(TaskExecutor jobTaskExecutor) {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("sync_async_investigation_test")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .start(syncFlow())
            .next(wrapperFlow(jobTaskExecutor))
            .end()
            .build();
}
```

Currently output looks like this:

```
2019-08-08 15:16:04.444  INFO 16292 --- [           main] h.w.c.ParallelFlowConfig$CountingTasklet : BEFORE sync_flow_step1 has been executed on thread main
2019-08-08 15:16:09.445  INFO 16292 --- [           main] h.w.c.ParallelFlowConfig$CountingTasklet : AFTER sync_flow_step1 has been executed on thread main
2019-08-08 15:16:09.474  INFO 16292 --- [           main] h.w.c.ParallelFlowConfig$CountingTasklet : BEFORE sync_flow_step2 has been executed on thread main
2019-08-08 15:16:14.474  INFO 16292 --- [           main] h.w.c.ParallelFlowConfig$CountingTasklet : AFTER sync_flow_step2 has been executed on thread main
2019-08-08 15:16:14.501  INFO 16292 --- [cust-job-exec-2] h.w.c.ParallelFlowConfig$CountingTasklet : BEFORE async_flow_1_step_1 has been executed on thread cust-job-exec-2
2019-08-08 15:16:14.524  INFO 16292 --- [cust-job-exec-1] h.w.c.ParallelFlowConfig$CountingTasklet : BEFORE async_flow_2_step_1 has been executed on thread cust-job-exec-1
2019-08-08 15:16:19.501  INFO 16292 --- [cust-job-exec-2] h.w.c.ParallelFlowConfig$CountingTasklet : AFTER async_flow_1_step_1 has been executed on thread cust-job-exec-2
2019-08-08 15:16:19.524  INFO 16292 --- [cust-job-exec-1] h.w.c.ParallelFlowConfig$CountingTasklet : AFTER async_flow_2_step_1 has been executed on thread cust-job-exec-1
2019-08-08 15:16:19.549  INFO 16292 --- [cust-job-exec-1] h.w.c.ParallelFlowConfig$CountingTasklet : BEFORE async_flow_2_step_2 has been executed on thread cust-job-exec-1
2019-08-08 15:16:24.550  INFO 16292 --- [cust-job-exec-1] h.w.c.ParallelFlowConfig$CountingTasklet : AFTER async_flow_2_step_2 has been executed on thread cust-job-exec-1
```